# How do I input a line break each time the length of a word in an ordered list changes?

Tags: python, list

I have already created a list of words that are ordered in descending order. I want to place a line break after each time the length of the words in the list changes.

```
my_list = ['PAID','BATCH','CAKE','MY','CABLE']

my_list.sort(key = len, reverse = True)

print(' '.join(words_in_final))
```

current output

```
BATCH CABLE CAKE PAID MY
```

desired result

```
BATCH CABLE

CAKE PAID

MY
```

or

```
length 5
BATCH CABLE

length 4
CAKE PAID

length 2
MY
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group strings by length having sorted them also by length:

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=len, reverse = True), key=len)]
# [['BATCH', 'CABLE'], ['PAID', 'CAKE'], ['MY']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby


my_list = ['PAID','BATCH','CAKE','MY','CABLE']
my_list.sort(key = len, reverse = True)

for l, v in groupby(my_list, len):
    print("length {}".format(l))
    print(" ".join(v))
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
length 5
BATCH CABLE

length 4
PAID CAKE

length 2
MY
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = ['PAID','BATCH','CAKE','MY','CABLE']

print(*(list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=len, reverse=True), key=len)), sep='\n')

# ['BATCH', 'CABLE']
# ['PAID', 'CAKE']
# ['MY']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple *iterative* approach:

```
w_len = 0
for w in my_list:
    print('\n' + w if (w_len and len(w) != w_len) else w, end=' ')
    w_len = len(w)
```

- `(w_len and len(w) != w_len)` - check if current word's length is not equal to a previous word's length

The output:

```
BATCH CABLE 
PAID CAKE 
MY
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = ['PAID','BATCH','CAKE','MY','CABLE']

my_list.sort(key = len, reverse = True)

current_length = len(my_list[0])
s = ""
for word in my_list:
    if len(word) < current_length:
        s += "\n"
        current_length = len(word)
    s += f"{word} "

print(s)
```

Comment: The requirement is that whenever the length __changes__, not only when it decreases. You only consider the case where the length of the next work is lower.

Comment: But it is a sorted list. It always decreases.